# Empty categories are not listed - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to show empty categories in the list.What is wrong with this code?

```
function cat_list(){
    $args = array(
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'orderby' => "name",
    'order' => "ASC" );
    $categories = get_categories(args);
    foreach($categories as $category){
    echo '<li><a href="' .get_category_link($category->term_id) . '"> '. $category->name . '</a></li>';

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing `$` while passing arguments to `get_categories`. Here's the fixed one.

```
function cat_list(){
    $args = array(
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'orderby' => "name",
    'order' => "ASC" );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach($categories as $category){
    echo '<li><a href="' .get_category_link($category->term_id) . '"> '. $category->name . '</a></li>';

}
```

Comment: You save my day . Thank a lot .